# I need to convert some Delphi 7 code to Seattle, but I cannot use the predefined function result "Result"

Tags: function, delphi, return, return-type, delphi-10-seattle

This works on Delphi 7:

```
Function T(Noegle : String) : String;
Begin
  Result:= Noegle;
End;
```

but fails on Seattle with this errormessage:

> [dcc32 Error] Tekster.pas(34): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Result'

I assume it is disabled by default, since I see Return used in code snippets on this site so I assume it must work, but I have been unable to locate where I turn it on and off.

`Result` is used in hundreds of functions in the old code, so I would be a happy boy if someone could tell me how to enable it.

Comment: What is *Sierra*?

Comment: I also don't know what this Sierra is. Does it use Delphi as a programming language? BTW, you mention `Return` instead of `Result` in your explanation. Maybe this Sierra uses `Return` and not `Result`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Seattle. Seattle is Delphi 10. Result is an automatic defined variable, you van use to return function results. Like described here: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=result

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of what Delphi and `Result` are; what I wasn't aware of is what the heck *Sierra* was, as it's not a Delphi version and Google or this site know nothing about it. If you had properly identified it as **Seattle** in the first place, and added the appropriate [tag:delphi] and [tag:delphi-10-seattle] tags, you would have had this post last night instead of having to wait almost 24 hours. Please be more clear in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ken, it is working now. I don't know how to give points for answers, but I can only give it 1 point. Hope thats the correct way, but if not please let me know what is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatic `Result` variable is available when extended syntax is enabled. To do so, use *Project->Options* from the IDE main menu, then go to *Delphi Compiler->Compiling->Syntax options*, and make sure that *Extended syntax* is checked.

the below dialog is captured from Berlin 10.1, but should be virtually identical to the one in Seattle 10:

[image: Project Options Compiling Dialog]

Comment: Might be worth noting that normally, a brand new Delphi install has this enabled by default. Somehow, it got disabled, probably by a user. I've used many Delphi versions and every function I write uses `Result`.